# how to inject the input field with the uploaded image url and how to submit the url with the form to mongodb?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, image, file-upload, cloudinary

disclaimer: this is not a replica of another post, I am trying a different approach to get the solution of this problem.
problem: cloudinary most recent uploaded image overwrites all displayed images
goal: to get the uploaded image url to be submitted alongside with the form to the backend (user choses the image and input field auto populates ) , in the back end I will be able to retrieve the image url which will have a mongodb id related to the form data so I woulld inject the img tag with the url of different image each time I upload an image
The way the app is set up : I have a form and. GUI to display the data. the form is stored inside (state) and I am using Cloudinary to upload the images which store the uploaded image inside a different state called (image). so far I have managed to get the url of the uploaded image but I need a way to submit it alongside with the form

any ideas how to do that ??

```
form 

  <form  onSubmit={props.handleSubmit} >
    <div >
  
  <div  >
  <label >Track name<input name="track" value={props.state.newTrack.track} onChange={props.handleChange}  /></label> 

  </div>
  <div >
  <label >Artist name<input name="artist" value={props.state.newTrack.artist} onChange={props.handleChange}  /></label>    

  </div>
  <div >
  <label  >album<input name="album" value={props.state.newTrack.album} onChange={props.handleChange}  /></label>

  </div>
  <div  >
  <label > Year<input name="year" value={props.state.newTrack.year} onChange={props.handleChange}  /></label>

  </div>
  <div  >
  <label >URL<input name="url" value={props.image} value={props.state.newTrack.url} onChange={props.handleSubmit}   /></label> 

  </div>



  <div  >
  <label > Upload<input name="url" type="file"    
    // value={props.state.newTrack.url}
     onChange={(e) => {
        setImageSelected(e.target.files[0]);

      
  
        
         }} /> 
         </label>
  </div>

    
    <button class="formdiv" onClick={uploadImage} > {props.state.editMode ? 'Edit ' : 'Add '}</button>
    </div>
  </form>

cloudinary upload image function
const [imageSelected, setImageSelected] = useState('');
console.log(imageSelected)
const uploadImage = () => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', imageSelected)
    formData.append('upload_preset', 'musicimages')
    Axios.post(
        '   https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dklcmfo0q/image/upload', formData)
    .then((res) => {
        props.setImage(res.data.url);
      })
};





function create track 
function createTrack(data){
    return fetch(BASE_URL, {
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-type' : 'Application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(res => res.json())
```

setting state of tracks

const track = await createTrack(state.newTrack);
// console.log(image)

```
  setState({
    tracks: [...state.tracks, track],
    newTrack: {
      track: "",
      artist:"",
      album: "",
      year:"",
      url:""
 
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file imageSelected that you are uploading with `fd.append(‘file’, imageSelected);` is a file object and not just the name of the file.
You can verify by logging it. Here’s some sample vanilla JS that might help. https://codepen.io/team/Cloudinary/pen/QgpyOK

Comment: I don’t think that works for me though, my issue is that I have a state that gets its data from a form , when the user submits all the data gets stored in mongodb  and displayed on screen, within that form I want to upload images with cloudinary, have the response url sent with the state as a url string and so it would get displayed.